# How to use Fake appupdatemanager for testing?

Tags: java, android, in-app-update

I have a code to check for any updates on the play store for my app, here is the code below.

```
private AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager;
int REQUEST_APP_UPDATE=888;
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_starternew);
  checkforupdate();

 public void checkforupdate{
          appUpdateManager =AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(Starternew.this);
 appUpdateManager
    .getAppUpdateInfo()
    .addOnSuccessListener(
            appUpdateInfo -> {
                if ((appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
                    try {
                        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                appUpdateInfo,
                                AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                                this,
                                REQUEST_APP_UPDATE);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            //}
});}
```

Below is the onresume method

```
@Override
   protected onResume(){
 super.onResume();
 appUpdateManager
    .getAppUpdateInfo()
    .addOnSuccessListener(
            appUpdateInfo ->{
                if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()==UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS){
                    try {
                        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                appUpdateInfo,
                                AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                                this,
                                REQUEST_APP_UPDATE
                        );
                    }catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

   // )
}}
```

I was informed of a class know as Fake appupdatemanager to test if it works or not but am not quite sure how it works. I tried changing private AppUpdateManager to private Fake appupdatemanager but to no avail, and this will be my first time loading an app onto the play store, how can I test my code using the same Fake appupdatemanager.